# ng-show not working properly on initial page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

So I was working on a webpage using html, css and Angular.js and I wanted to display the page based on what the user has selected on the dropdown list. The "filter" when the user selects his/her choice works perfectly but initially when the page is loaded I could not get the entire page content to be displayed, instead it displays a blank page.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="data.id as data.name for data in myData.categories"></select>
    <div class="main"  >
        <ul id="cbp-ntaccordion" class="cbp-ntaccordion" ng-repeat="data in myData.profiles" ng-show="selectedOption == data.category" >
            <li class="cbp-ntopen">
                <h3 class="cbp-nttrigger">{{data.name}}</h3>
                <div class="cbp-ntcontent">
```

I'm getting an error like:

> angular.js:13708Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ngRepeat/dupes?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: yes, it goes something like "angular.js:13708Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/ngRepeat/dupes?"

Comment: You'll need to use a `track by [property]` here to avoid the dupe error. It could be the built in $index property, or a property on you objects you are repeating. Something like `ng-repeat="data in myData.profiles track by $index"`

Comment: ok,but how about the page initially loading blank,can you help me with that

Comment: For ng-model purposes you should use an object. However, the page loads fine if you remove the ng-show?

Comment: yes but my aim here is to initially load the page with all of my contents there and then to hide certain div elements based on my expression while the user selects a catagory from the dropdown list

Comment: Can you post some of your data in `myData.categories` or `myData` would be even better?  Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: i am new to this website, bow do i edit my question and is there a means to send you guys my whole code so that you can see what is wrong with it

Comment: Try to create the object in your controller `$scope.selectedOption={option:1}` and use ng-model="selectedOption.option" instead

Comment: @Iker Vázquez still wouldnot work....can i email you my project and see what's wrong with it as a whole

Answer (score 0):

You may use ng-value="defalutvalue" so your code is something like that

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-value="defalutvalue" ng-options="data.id as data.name for data in myData.categories"></select>
<div class="main"  >
    <ul id="cbp-ntaccordion" class="cbp-ntaccordion" ng-repeat="data in myData.profiles" ng-show="selectedOption == data.category" >
        <li class="cbp-ntopen">
            <h3 class="cbp-nttrigger">{{data.name}}</h3>
            <div class="cbp-ntcontent">
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error that you mentioned, I think you are not giving Angular a way to figure out how to note your object as unique.  Use a `track by` expression in your `ng-repeat`.

So your `ng-repeat` would become: `ng-repeat="data in myData.profiles track by $index"`

See the [Tracking and Duplicates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates) section of ngRepeat documentation.

```
<ul id="cbp-ntaccordion" class="cbp-ntaccordion" ng-repeat="data in myData.profiles track by $index" ng-show="selectedOption == data.category">
```

Comment: fixed the ngRepeat:dupes error and read the documentation...thank you dude, but could you help me with the ng-show problem

Comment: @Harun Are you getting new console errors other than the `[ngRepeat:dupes]` error?